# elasticsearch problems with queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I'm planning use elasticsearch in my project but I'm a beginner. My document will look like this

```
{
   "title":"Investment secrets",
   "body":"What they don't tell you ...",
   "tags":[
      "shares",
      "equities"
   ],
   "comments":[
      {
         "name":"Mary Brown",
         "comment":"Lies, lies, lies",
         "age":42,
         "stars":1,
         "date":"2014-10-16",
         "priority":[
            {
               "prior":1,
               "some fields":1
            },
            {
               "prior":3,
               "some fields":3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"John Smith",
         "comment":"You're making it up!",
         "age":28,
         "stars":2,
         "date":"2014-10-16",
         "priority":[
            {
               "prior":2,
               "some fields":2
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

how i can get result as title, body tags and coments fields where date is max (if two date is same) and comments.priority fields where prior is min for comments where date is max ?? it's posibble? thanks for help

Comment: Please provide a sample output.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
"fields": ["comments.name", "title", "body", "tags"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  { "match": { "comments.name": "john" }},
                  { "match": { "comments.age":  28     }}
                ]
        }}}}
      ]
}}}



{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":
{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":
{"total":1,"max_score":2.4114075,"hits":
[{"_index":"test","_type":"produkt","_id":"1","_score":2.4114075,"fields":
{"comments.name":["Mary Brown","John Smith"],"title":["Investment 
secrets"],"body":["What they don't tell you ..."],"tags":
["shares","equities"]}}]}}
```

how return only name John Smith?

ok solution is   "inner_hits" : {}

but the next problem is how to get comments where date is max, e.q in sql

select * from table where comments.date = (select max(comments.date) from table)